# Checkbox seleccionados en tabla html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

gracias a una aclaración de Jorge Gomez, tengo solucionado el saber los checkbox seleccionados en una tabla HTML:

```
function grupoeliminar(id,ntabla,tablamysql ){

$("#"+ntabla+" input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
             alert($(this).val());
        });
 

}
```

Necesito afinar el código para saber solo los checkbox seleccionados en una columna en concreto.

Sería para imprimir, ó borrar los registros mysql relaccionados....

Gracias por todo...

Comment: ¿Una columna de dónde?

Comment: de una tabla html.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna manera de identificar esa columna? Como que sus elementos pertenezcan a determinada clase o que tengan siempre el mismo índice dentro del elemento que los contiene.

Comment: puedes usar el evento `onclick` y apoyarte del evento `e` y obtener su `traget`

Answer (score 1):

parece que esto está funcionando:

```
$("#"+ntabla+" tr").find('td:eq(0) input:checkbox:checked' ).each(function () {
             alert($(this).val());
        });
```

Gracias...